# Posting array of objects in request in form-data in django api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am using Django Restframework for apis. I am working on a POST api where I need to send an array of objects in form-data. When I tried it in raw data it is working perfectly. But when I use form-data in postman and placing the value in array, It is causing problem.

The key value pair i am using in raw data is

```
 {  "services": [
        {
            "category_image": "",
            "category_name": "construction",
            "budget_min": "0-1000",
            "budget_max": "0-1000",
            "distance_min": "200",
            "distance_max": "500",
            "projects": [
        {
            "category_image": "",
            "category_name": "residential",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "project_name": "single family",
                    "project_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "project_name": "multi family",
                    "project_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "project_name": "big family",
                    "project_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "category_image": "",
            "category_name": "hospitality",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "project_name": "health care",
                    "project_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "5"
                },
                {
                    "project_name": "hotels",
                    "project_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "service_name": "wall",
                    "service_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "service_name": "kitchen",
                    "service_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "service_name": "outdoor",
                    "service_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "category_image": "",
            "category_name": "driving",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "service_name": "car",
                    "service_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "5"
                },
                {
                    "service_name": "bike",
                    "service_image": "",
                    "parent_id": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In form-data I am using services as the key and the array as value.

My code to retrieve value is :

```
data = request.data.get['services']
```

While using raw data i am getting it properly but not in form-data.
I printed the request , it is coming perfect in raw data but in form-data it takes everything inside a string . The response looks like -

```
"[\n   {\n      \"min_price\":\"5\",\n      \"max_price\":\"50\",\n      \"category_image\":\"\",\n      \"service_name\":\"plumb\",\n      \"projects\":[\n         {\n            \"category_image\":\"\",\n            \"project_name\":\"personal\",\n            \"sub_category\":[\n               {\n                  \"project_name\":\"single family\",\n                  \"project_image\":\"\",\n                  \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n               },\n               {\n                  \"project_name\":\"multi family\",\n                  \"project_image\":\"\",\n                  \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n               },\n               {\n                  \"project_name\":\"big family\",\n                  \"project_image\":\"\",\n                  \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n               }\n            ]\n         },\n         {\n            \"category_image\":\"\",\n            \"project_name\":\"hospita\",\n            \"sub_category\":[\n               {\n                  \"project_name\":\"health care\",\n                  \"project_image\":\"\",\n                  \"parent_id\":\"5\"\n               },\n               {\n                  \"project_name\":\"hotels\",\n                  \"project_image\":\"\",\n                  \"parent_id\":\"5\"\n               }\n            ]\n         }\n      ],\n      \"sub_category\":[\n         {\n            \"service_name\":\"wall\",\n            \"service_image\":\"\",\n            \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n         },\n         {\n            \"service_name\":\"kitchen\",\n            \"service_image\":\"\",\n            \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n         },\n         {\n            \"service_name\":\"outdoor\",\n            \"service_image\":\"\",\n            \"parent_id\":\"1\"\n         }\n      ]\n   }\n]"
```

Comment: print the `request` and see if your data is there in the 1st place, if so then just see under which key it is. Hope this helps

Comment: can you please show your complete code of view? seems you might using incorrect method

Comment: @N.Ivanov printed the request , it is coming perfect in raw data but in form-data it takes everything inside a string. I do'nt want to take everything in strings. I will not allow me to iterate for loop over it.

Comment: maybe read [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser)

Comment: Why would you want to send this as form-data? You should use JSON.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It is compulsory as i have to send an image as well which i can not use in raw data

Comment: Then you have conflicting requirements. A structure like this cannot be sent as form data. One possibility would be to send this data as JSON *within* a form field, then parse it out via `json.loads(request.POST['json_data'])`.